# Feature extraction from LSTM to Sklearn models

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, lstm

I've a LSTM model and i want to extract features from this LSTM to send it into a Random Forest or a logistic regression on Sklearn.

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(t+1, n_features))
x=tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
x1=tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, dropout=0.1, return_sequences=False)(x)
o=tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,activation='softmax')(x1)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = o)
```

so i want to use x1 as the input of my Random forest.
Any idea ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a model with the desired input/output tensors. For example:

```
feat_extractor = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x1)

# Then, assuming X is a batch of input patterns:

feats = feat_extractor.predict(X)
```